# HP Compaq Pro 6305, upgrade video card and RAM memory

Tags: graphics-cards, memory, pcie, power, smps

I need to upgrade to a dedicated graphics card for an HP 1850 motherboard and also upgrade the RAM.
The power supply is 240W; it has no additional cards.

[image: Spare Number: 613762-001]

[image: PCI slots]

I looked for information but I have doubts if the graphics card and RAM I have quoted will work in the computer.

### Video card

[image: NVIDIA T600, top view.]

I am interested in the [NVIDIA T600 card](https://www.techpowerup.com/gpu-specs/t600.c3796), in the [equipment specifications](https://support.hp.com/us-en/document/c03522674) and in the [maintenance and service guide](http://h10032.www1.hp.com/ctg/Manual/c03916058#d0e6974) I find that the compatible video cards are similar (PCIe 3.0 x16, 128 bits); according to the information I found the maximum power is 40W and the [suggested power supply](https://www.techpowerup.com/gpu-specs/t600.c3796) is 200W.

### RAM memory

[image: Kingston KVR16N11/8]

I would like to install 2 Kingston KVR16N11/8 modules (DDR3 - 8GB - 1600MHz).

Given all of the above, are they compatible? I am on a tight budget.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Gpu: Yes, but if it's too high, you cannot get the panel back on. This should not be an issue in terms of functionality though

RAM: Should be